# MVC controller dependency on static service class -- testability concern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, unit-testing

I am new at testing and am looking at unit testing some legacy code in maintenance.  The controllers are structured around static service calls to get data.  I am not sure of the best path forward, but am thinking either restructure the static class to an instance class or dig deeper into testability methods.  This code snippet is a simply example of what I run into over and over.  Thanks in advance for any advice.  staticMedServiceHelper is a static class with a static Use method utilizing WCF ChannelFactory etc. BTW, if you have any good learning resources for WCF/MVC/Testing please let me know.
Thanks again.

```
public ActionResult Documents(DocumentsForRequirementViewModel model)
{
        staticMedServiceHelper<IMedService>.Use(proxy =>
        {
            var requirment = proxy.GetRequirementById(model.Id);
            var dtos = (IEnumerable<DocumentDTO>)requirement.GetType().GetProperty(model.PropertyName).GetValue(requirement, null);

            model.Documents = Mapper.Map(dtos, new List<DocumentViewModel>());
        });

        return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where `wcf` is involved here; perhaps there is some misunderstanding?

Comment: I'd vote for replacing it. Static class aside, this thing requires you to use reflection on whatever you pull out of it which is a huge glaring warning sign that it's badly designed in the first place.

Comment: staticMedServiceHelper<T> is a static class utilizing ChannelFacotry WCF.  Perhaps that information was not relevant.  My main question is concerned with testability of the controller methods.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My tip to break dependency is simple : for statics, wrap them in instance classes.

Suppose you have a static logger (i've really seen this in production code mind you)

```
public static class Logger
{
  public static void Log(string message)
  {
    //logging logic here..
  }
}

public ActionResult Documents(DocumentsForRequirementViewModel model)
{
  Logger.Log("GET action on Documents");
  //bla bla
}
```

In this case the dependency is clear on the static implementation of the logger.

We can create a new logger:

```
public class LogWrapper
{
  public void Log(string message)
  {
    Logger.Log(message);
  }
}
```

And use that in our code:

```
public ActionResult Documents(DocumentsForRequirementViewModel model)
{
  LogWrapper logger = new LogWrapper();
  loggerr.Log("GET action on Documents");
}
```

Note:

This is just a simple example. Normally all external dependencies would be Interfaced first of all and then for static implementations just create a instance wrapper.

If you more complex scenarios of dependecy, you could create Decorators to help you with the transformation from static to instance and delegating the code to the static implementation.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I wish I could vote that answer up but my reputation is too small.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note, though, that you are not gaining any testability whatsoever as long as you instantiate the Logger inside the class that is being tested. If you want any testability, you need set the logger externally, preferrably using constructor arguments (and dependency injection).